# Navigation Drawer Click stops app and takes back to launch Page

Tags: android

I am new to java and android development, have only 3 apps under my belt.

The Problem:
When I click a navigation tab to take me to another activity, it says unfortunately app has stopped and brings me back to the launcher page..

Things I have already looked at fixing:
Grandle Console doesn't reference any errors in the code.
Grandle Console doesn't reference any missing dependancies. 
I have ensured all versioning is correct.
I am not using depreciated methods.

The app works if I create my own navigation with buttons, this simple functionality will really streamline the app. It is an app for hiking to log gps with journal entries while mapping a hike using fine-location.

This is the first I have built with the navigation drawer.  I have spent days on this problem alone and have finally decided to ask for help, hopefully someone can help out.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    String myurl="file:///android_asset/index.html";
    WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(myurl);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.activity_main) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.activity_main:
            Intent h= new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(h);
            break;

        case R.id.activity_entry:
            Intent e= new Intent(MainActivity.this,EntryActivity.class);
            startActivity(e);
            break;

        case R.id.activity_list:
            Intent l= new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListActivity.class);
            startActivity(l);
            break;

        case R.id.activity_bluetooth:
            Intent b= new Intent(MainActivity.this,BluetoothActivity.class);
            startActivity(b);
            break;
        }   


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should have something in the Log Cat window that details why the program crashed. That will help you get assistance if you post the relevant part here

Comment: No Mike, There is no errors in any of the windows.  No log as to the crashes.. I do not use an emulator, only my phone. Emulator crashes my computer every time i use it.

Comment: Even on the phone there will be logging messages. Look in the tab labeled "Android" (or "LogCat" if you are using Android Studio 3.0). And play with the Verbose and No Filters settings. You might be suppressing the errors. If your app is crashing it is nearly certain there is something interesting in the log to help.

Comment: With no filters, in verbose, debug, error, info, and assert, there are no errors at all.

Comment: Let me also clarify, the app is not broken. It installs, loads, and opens. Takes me through the first 3 activities.  Then once I get to the main activity, i use the navigation drawer to click through to the other 5 main activities as listed in the code.  Once I try to use the navigation drawer links to switch between activities, is when it breaks and says Every activity works though.

Comment: Ok, make sure the left field (same row as the filters) has the correct device connected. I assume your phone is still physically connected after Android Studio has installed the APK. Running on the phone (even without errors) should generate a lot of chatter on the log window, especially without filtering.

Comment: Look at above comment, I have edited it.

Comment: My phone has never been connected.  Once I want to try, I try it on my phone.  A previous version of this app, I had my own button navigation i had used.  I am switching to the navigation drawer to streamline the app.  It will really clean it up.  But I have not been able to transition to different activities while using the drawer links.

Comment: I assume[d] you are using Android Studio... when you press the green Play button it builds and installs the app onto your phone via a USB cable. Leave the USB cable connected then you will have all the logging features I refer to.

Comment: 11-09 18:38:46.263 15185-15185/com.jason.v4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.jason.v4, PID: 15185
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jason.v4/com.jason.v4.EntryActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: Please post your error log so that we can know the issue.

Comment: Android, The error is above

Answer (score 1):

First of All, If you put the error log, then that would be very helpful to get quick help. However, as a new developer,

- Gradle is a build system, it actually build your project according to
  the configuration (managing versions, artifacts, dependencies, etc).
- Gradle Console won't show the Errors, you'll find that from Android Monitor/Logcat.
- You may mistakenly do some common mistakes

  - Declaration of activities in the manifest.
  - looking for an Id of Resources that not belongs to the current layout.
  - Null Value Exception.